# Launch Python debugger while simultaneously executing module as script

Tags: python, pdb

When developing a Python package, it's very convenient to use the `-m` option to run modules inside the package as scripts for quick testing. For example, for `somepackage` with module `somemodule.py` inside it, invoking

```
python -m somepackage.somemodule
```

from the directory where `somepackage` resides will run `somemodule.py` as though the submodule were `__main__`. Using this calling syntax is especially important if the package is using explicit relative imports as described [here](https://ncoghlan_devs-python-notes.readthedocs.org/en/latest/python_concepts/import_traps.html#the-double-import-trap).

Similarly, it is also convenient to use the `-m` option to debug a script, as in

```
python -m pdb somescript.py
```

Is there any way to do both at the same time? That is, can I call a module as though it were a script and simultaneously launch into the debugger? I realize I can go into the code itself and insert `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` where I want to break, but I'm trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After experimenting with this for quite some time, it turns out that this approach actually works:

```
python -c "import runpy; import pdb; pdb.runcall(runpy.run_module, 'somepackage.somemodule', run_name='__main__')"
```

For some reason, the use of `pdb.runcall` over `pdb.run` is important.

Comment: pdb.run would expect a string, not a callable.  
`python -c "import runpy; import pdb; pdb.run(\"runpy.run_module( 'somepackage.somemodule', run_name='__main__')\")"`  
works just as well, but it's more cumbersome

Answer (score 25):

There are [efforts](https://bugs.python.org/issue9325) [underway](https://bugs.python.org/issue32206) to solve this in Python itself. Looks like with Python 3.7, you can do:

```
python -m pdb -m somepackage.somemodule
```

And I've provided [a backport](https://pypi.org/project/backports.pdb) for older Python versions (2.7+):

```
pip install backports.pdb
python -m backports.pdb -m somepackage.somemodule
```

Comment: `python -m pdb -m path.to.module` works perfectly for me in python 3.9.5

Answer (score 3):

Building on @jed's answer, I built this module:

```
import pdb
import runpy
import sys


def main():
    module = sys.argv[1]
    sys.argv[1:] = sys.argv[2:]
    pdb.runcall(runpy.run_module, module, run_name='__main__')


__name__ == '__main__' and main()
```

Put that module as `mpdb.py` anywhere in your Python Path (current directory works), then you may invoke:

```
python -m mpdb somepackage.somemodule even with args
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another option that also works with command line arguments.

It's generally a good idea to wrap your script's logic in a `main` function. You can then have `main` take in an optional list of arguments to override `sys.argv`. Here's an example called `argdemo.py`:

```
def main(cmd_line_args=None):
    import argparse

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("number", help="a number", type=int)

    # allow cmd_line_args to override sys.argv
    if cmd_line_args is None:
        args = parser.parse_args()
    else:
        args = parser.parse_args(cmd_line_args)

    print("The number is {}".format(args.number))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This module can be run as usual:

```
$ python -m argdemo 2
> The number is 2
```

Or it can be run with `pdb` by calling `main()` directly:

```
$ python -c "import pdb; import argdemo; pdb.runcall(argdemo.main, ['2'])"
(Pdb) continue
> The number is 2
```

(Notice that `cmd_line_args` has to be a list of strings just like `argv` would be).

As an added bonus, when your module has an import-able `main` function, you can write unit tests for it in the same way =)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (debug python module as a script with -m option)

I created a scratch

```
import runpy

if __name__ == '__main__':
    runpy.run_module('somepackage.somemodule', run_name="__main__", alter_sys=True)
```

idea taken from: [Intellij/Pycharm can't debug Python modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955520/intellij-pycharm-cant-debug-python-modules)