# Calling Python package from command line / PyCharm

Tags: python-2.7

I am creating a Python package, I anticipate that it will be called both by command line and from other scripts. Here is a simplified version of my file structure:

```
GREProject/
    __init__.py
    __main__.py
    Parsing.py
```

Parseing.py contains a method, parse(), it takes two arguments, an input file and an output file. I am trying to figure out the proper code for "__main__.py" so that when the following is called from the command line or terminal the arguments will be passed to "parse()":

```
Python GREProject -i input.file -o output.file
```

I have tried this numerous ways but they have all met with failure, I do believe I need the "-m" flag for the interpreter but more than that I don't know. Example with the flag:

```
Python -m GREProject -i input.file -o output.file
```

When running the later command I receive the following error:

```
Import by filename is not supported.
```

Presumably from this line:

```
from . import Parsing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, turns out this was a problem with my IDE, PyCharm. No idea why I recieved this error but I have setting that fixed it:

```
Import by filename is not supported.
```

For the record here are the options I set in my Pycharm project

```
Script:
    GREProject
Script parameters:
    -i .\GREProject\pr2.nyc1 -o .\GREProject\Test.pkl
Enviroment variables:
    PYTHONUNBUFFERED=1
Python interpreter:
    Python 2.7.11 (c:\Python27\python.exe)
Interpreter options:
    -m
Working directory:
    C:\Users\probert.dan\PycharmProjects
```

Here is an explanation of the options:

- **Script:** This is the script to run, by default PyCharm will only insert absolute references to .py files, nothing prevents you from manually typing in a relative reference, in this case it is the GREProjects folder.
- **Script Parameters:** These are passed onto the script itself, in this case I am telling my script that the input file is ".\GREProject\pr2.nyc1" which means, look the file "pr2.nyc1" in the "GREProject" directory below the current working directory.
- **Environment variables:** This was set by PyCharm and left unchanged.
- **Python interpreter:** My active interpreter.
- **Interpreter options:** The option here tells python that we are calling a module, python then knows to access the "__main__.py" file.
- **Working directory:** The directory the script is run from, I chose the directory above "GREProject"

For reference here is the contents of my "__main__.py file":

```
from . import Parsing
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Parse flags.')
parser.add_argument('-i', help='Import file.')
parser.add_argument('-o', help='(Optional) Output file.')
arguments = parser.parse_args()
Parsing.parse(arguments.i, arguments.o)
```

It is also important to note that debugging in PyCharm is not possible like this. Here is the solution to debugging: [Intellij/Pycharm can't debug Python modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28955520/intellij-pycharm-cant-debug-python-modules)

Comment: Accepting this answer (by clicking the checkmark) will mark this thread as solved. No need to edit the title ;-)