# How to invoke pdb from command line while running library module as a script?

Tags: python, pdb

I am invoking the python interpreter like the following

```
python -m MyModule.main
```

Is there an easy way to invoke the the pdb debugger via the command line in this use case ?

Comment: One option I found is to call `pdb.set_trace()` in the function but I do not want to modify the source every time.

Comment: I find the `python -m pdb my_script.py` way of invoking pdb very convenient. Is something similar possible in this use case ?

Comment: You simply run the `main.py` of the module. That's what `-m` does.

Comment: In that case I am getting a relative import in non package error. 
`from .Config import Config
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
Uncaught exception. Entering post mortem debugging`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Launch Python debugger while simultaneously executing module as script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18166362/launch-python-debugger-while-simultaneously-executing-module-as-script)

Answer (score 0):

You can execute pdb on a python file which has same effect as executing `python -m MyModule.main` using the runpy module (see [documentation](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0338/#id16)) e.g as a command on a UNIX-like OS:

```bash
python -m pdb <(echo "import runpy;runpy.run_module('MyModule.main', run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)")
```

This could be generalised into a function that you could add to your bash_profile:

```bash
function pdb-m {
  python -m pdb <(echo "import runpy;runpy.run_module('$1', run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)") "${@:2}"
}
```